# Constructing a WPF SplitButton with a ComboBox

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox, split-button

I've seen some examples online, but all seemed overly complex.  I'd just like to have a ComboBox with the background being a custom image of a button.  Unfortunately there's no way I can see to set background to an image.

Comment: So it's unclear, are you asking how to create a "SplitButton" or are you wanting to know how to set a background image?

Comment: Both are part of the same thing.  As a major step in creating the SplitButton I need the background of the ComboBox to have the same image as all the other buttons in the project.